# Is there a way to enable borderless window mode for Diablo 2?

Tags: diablo-ii

I've become a bit spoiled with all the newer games offering [borderless window mode](http://pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/Borderless_Fullscreen_Windowed)<sup>1</sup>. Is there anyway to enable it for Diablo 2? Or am I stuck with the nasty border around my window?

<sup>1. Borderless fullscreen windowed is the display option of having a game run in a window but appear to be running in fullscreen.</sup>

Comment: What do you mean by border vs borderless?

Comment: It is basically a convenience feature for people with multiple monitors. It stops the game from minimizing/freaking out whenever you swap to look at a program in the other monitor. A couple games off the top of my head that support it are: civilization 5 and league of legends. So, it acts like a windowed program, but does not display the border AKA minimize, window, close buttons

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm inclined to suggest that if the game wasn't coded in such a way that it won't be possible.

Given the age of Diablo II and the very recent rise in popularity of boarderless windowed mode I think it's very unlikely.

Comment: It is possible that a mod could be developed to enable such behaviour, based on existence of the Diablo II multi resolution mod (http://www.moddb.com/games/diablo-2/news/d2multires), but at this current time it doesn't seem to exist. It would also not allow you to play on Battle.net as that requires an original version of the game - mods are not permitted on Battle.net

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. In fact it works with any and every program. Please check my tutorial  on [my Operating Systems class website](http://elf.cs.pub.ro/so/wiki/laboratoare/resurse/injections). It might be bannable, but not more than with Fraps or MSI Afterburner. If you get into trouble contact Blizzard support and link them the website to revert the ban.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way of using a launcher called [D2MultiRes 1.02](http://www.moddb.com/games/diablo-2/downloads/d2multires-version-102) which will basically launch the game in a window at a higher resolution. You should be able to manipulate the screen to a borderless window by using some tools. The only stipulation is that this tool requires 1.12 which is not the latest Blizzard patch for the game, meaning that if you used it, you can't play online.

More information is available [at the PC Gaming Wiki](http://pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/Diablo_II#High_resolution_support).

Comment: Can you clarify how you can change the screen to borderless? You say with "some tools", are there specific tools, or are they included with D2MultiRes in some way?

Comment: Some tools are clarified in this article: http://pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/Borderless_Fullscreen_Windowed - try this program Borderless Windowed: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4oYQZFLBkAg